# Can I have more than one relationship between two tables?

Tags: database-design

I want to make database for report maintenance.

I have 3 tables:

1. employees
2. header_maintenance_report
3. detail_maintenance_report

[image: my database table]

`employees` table I have employee_id and then in the `header_maintenance_report`table I use the employee_id ( *Foreign Key* ) as report maintenance maker.

Can I use another employee_id in the `detail_maintenance_report` table?

I use employee id in `detail_maintenance_report` table as team maintenance from report maintenance maker.

Every maintenance requires a lot of employees so I use `detail_maintenance_report`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. You have two different relationships here.

1. A one-to-one relationship between employees and header_maintenance_report via employee_id on each table.
2. A many-to-many relationship between employees and header_maintenance_report via the keys on detail_maintenance_report.

So long as you know what these two relationships represent (e.g. report author and report viewers) then there's no problem with that, however... I'd suggest you think carefully about naming. From your wording it's not clear exactly what the relationships represent but you might want to think twice about the use of "header" and "detail" in the table names as it sounds like the "detail" table is actually a joining table between the other two.

When using many-to-many relationships a common approach is to use the names of the two tables you're joining as the name for the join table, e.g.

1. employees
2. maintenance_reports
3. employees_to_maintenance_reports

Edit, see this example: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/03743/1

Comment: thank you matthew :)
you give me the best explanation for me and give me a example :)

Comment: To expand a little, don't propogate, say, the name "employee_id" everywhere you use it. Name it something meaningful according to the role it plays in the table of use. In header_maintenance_report, it might be "maker_id". In detail_maintenance_report it might be "member_id" or "viewer_id" or "editor_id" or whatever the role being played here.